# Integrating OGRE 1.7.3 in Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, ogre3d

I try to embed ogre3d widget into qt widget on Ubuntu, but we see black screen.

When we ogre::Root::RenderWindow is used without parent widget (as a main window) everything works. But when we create ogre::Root::RenderWindow as a child window of other main window, we encounter ogre fails to work.

Here is the code:

cpp: http://pastebin.com/Rbxa5btj

header: http://pastebin.com/F4w5eQ7d

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I needed to call the `XSync` method as shown below.  This is part of a `OgreWidget::initialize` method, where `OgreWidget` subclasses `QWidget`.  `initialize` is called as part of construction of `OgreWidget`, after `m_OgreRoot` is allocated and the render system is set.

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);

setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

Ogre::String winHandle;
QX11Info info = x11Info();
winHandle = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(info.display()));
winHandle += ":";
winHandle += Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned int)(info.screen()));
winHandle += ":";
winHandle += Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(winId()));

Ogre::NameValuePairList params;
params["parentWindowHandle"] = winHandle;
params["FSAA"] = Ogre::String("8");

int w = width();
int h = height();
// Need to call XSync or the window handles will be invalid.
XSync(info.display(), False);
m_OgreWindow =
      m_OgreRoot->createRenderWindow("OgreWidget_RenderWindow",
                                     qMax(w, 640), qMax(h, 480), false, &params);
```

Here is the same code modified for Qt 5.1.0.  `QX11Info` was removed for Qt 5.0.x, then added to the "extras" component for Qt 5.1.0.  The new `QX11Info` class has only static methods.

```
#include <QtX11Extras/QX11Info>
...
setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);

setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

Ogre::String winHandle;
winHandle = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(QX11Info::display()));
winHandle += ":";
winHandle += Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned int)(QX11Info::appScreen()));
winHandle += ":";
winHandle += Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(winId()));

Ogre::NameValuePairList params;
params["parentWindowHandle"] = winHandle;
params["FSAA"] = Ogre::String("8");

int w = width();
int h = height();
// Need to call XSync or the window handles will be invalid.
XSync(QX11Info::display(), False);
m_OgreWindow =
      m_OgreRoot->createRenderWindow("OgreWidget_RenderWindow",
                                     qMax(w, 640), qMax(h, 480), false, &params);
```